# make javafx jar prompt for Admin credentials with GUI while using sudo command

Tags: java, macos, javafx, terminal, jar

I'm trying to write a javafx application, which will install another pkg in mac device. I've used the command

```
sudo -v installer -pkg /Downloads/one.pkg -target /
```

to install the pkg on a button click from javafx application.

```
public class macinstall extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        Button button = new Button("Click");

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> event = ae -> install2();
        button.setOnAction(event);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 200, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void runProcess(String[] Command) {
        ProcessBuilder builderObj = new ProcessBuilder(Command);
        try {
            Process process = builderObj.start();
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void install2() {
        String[] installCommand = {"bash", "-c", "sudo -v installer -pkg /Downloads/one.pkg -target /"};
        runProcess(installCommand);
        System.out.println("Install Completed");
    }
}
```

This program works when I run it through terminal, admin password is asked in terminal.
but when I run as javafx application using jre. it's not asking for admin credentials.

Comment: So what actually happens? I would expect this just to hang...

Comment: Yes, It just hang. after clicking the button. Is there way to make gui popup to ask for admin credentials before processing the installation?

Comment: I think you need to 1. prompt the user for the password before starting the process, 2. use the `-S` option to `sudo`, and 3. send the password to the [process's standard input](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream())

Comment: You should probably also run the process in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion James_D.

String[] installCommand = {"osascript","-e","do shell script "installer -pkg /Downloads/one.pkg -target /" with administrator privileges"};

I used the above command,which accessed the GUI from OSX to give me the Pop up for User Authentication before Installing the pkg.

Now the User Authentication is processed like below image.

[image]

But I'm wondering, is there a possible way to change the Authentication message popped up in the image.
Like instead of "osascript wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this". is it possible to configure my preferred String or mention my application name there?

Comment: If you have a (additional) question, post a .. question :) - the answer section is for answers, exclusively

Comment: Okay, @kleopatra.